ImportError from Pandas while running XGBoost model on python
I am trying to run a basic XGBoost model on python (v 3.8.5), however getting an error that I can not resolve. Appreciate your help, thanks!
My code is as below:
import seaborn as sns
import pandas  as pd
import numpy   as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb

# Read data and drop categorical variables; split as X and y
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
X, y = diamonds.drop(['price', 'color', 'cut', 'clarity'], axis = 1), diamonds[['price']] 

# Split the data into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 1)

# Create regression matrices
dtrain_reg = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train, enable_categorical = True)
dtest_reg  = xgb.DMatrix(X_test,  y_test,  enable_categorical = True)


Getting an error at this stage:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a1090b4630fd> in <module>
      1 # Create regression matrices
----> 2 dtrain_reg = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train, enable_categorical = True)
      3 dtest_reg  = xgb.DMatrix(X_test,  y_test,  enable_categorical = True)
....
....
~\Downloads\New folder\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in pandas_transform_data(data)
    474     """Handle categorical dtype and extension types from pandas."""
    475     import pandas as pd
--> 476     from pandas import Float32Dtype, Float64Dtype
    477 
    478     result: List[np.ndarray] = []

ImportError: cannot import name 'Float32Dtype' from 'pandas' (C:\Users\lordp\Downloads\New folder\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py)


Please provide some more details, especially regarding the version of pandas used by you. According to the upstream code, pandas>= 1.2.0 is required - see https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/10476.
